# Calculate the number of multiplications and additions involved in evaluating $A^r$ for a given square matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Professor X asks two of his students P and Q to calculate the number of multiplications and additions involved in evaluating $A^r$ for a given square matrix $A$. P, being obedient, does the given job in the naive way and comes out with $s$ multiplications and $t$ additions. Q observes that $r = j \times k$, where $j > 1$ and $k > 1$ and evaluates $A^r$ as $(A^j)^k$ and observes that he had used $s'$ multiplications and $t'$ additions. Using the above compute $|s − s'|$ and $|t − t'|$.

Comment: I'm afraid you forgot to add the bonus question: what is the age of the captain? Sorry, but this site isn't for stunts or challenges, it is for mathematical questions and answers possibly being of general interest.

Answer (score 1):

Say that $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix; we are then comparing the cost (in multiplications and additions) of calculating $r-1=jk-1$ products of two $n\times n$ matrices with the cost of calculating $(j-1)+(k-1)=j+k-2$ products of two $n\times n$ matrices. Now

$$jk-1-(j+k-2)=jk-j-k+1=(j-1)(k-1)\;,$$

so if one such product costs $m$ multiplications and $a$ additions, we save $m(j-1)(k-1)$ multiplications and $a(j-1)(k-1)$ additions doing it Q’s way.

Each element of the product of two $n\times n$ matrices is the sum of $n$ products, so it is the result of $n$ multiplications and $n-1$ additions. There are $n^2$ entries in the product, so it takes $m=n^3$ multiplications and $a=n^2(n-1)$ additions to compute the product. Thus,

$$\begin{align*}
s&=n^3(r-1),\\
t&=n^2(n-1)(r-1),\\
s'&=n^3(j+k-2),\\
t'&=n^2(n-1)(j+k-2),\\
|s-s'|&=s-s'=n^3(j-1)(k-1),\text{ and}\\
|t-t'|&=t-t'=n^2(n-1)(j-1)(k-1)\;.
\end{align*}$$